# Passing position values into Twig

Tags: twig

I need to pass some values into my twig file. The defaults should be:

```
{% set pos.top|default(0) %}
{% set pos.right |default(0) %}
{% set pos.bottom |default(0) %}
{% set pos.left |default(0) %}
```

If no new values are given I don't need to use those, however, if either of the four is not 0 I need to add inline style

```
{% if ...(top == 2)... %}
    style="position: relative; top: 2px"
{% endif %}
```

How do I put it together?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
    {% set addInline = false %}
    {% for key, value in pos %}
        {% if value != 0 %}
            {% set addInline = true %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if addInline %}
        style="
            position: relative;
            {% for key, value in pos %}
                {% if value != 0 %}
                    {{ key }}: {{ value }}px;
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        "
    {% endif %}
```